# Chartjs v2 - format tooltip for multiple data sets (bar and line)

Tags: chart.js

Reading up a lot on how to format the tooltip in ChartJS v2.x utilizing the tooltip callback. I've had success thus far, but find that I'm unable to define two separate formats for the two data sets I have.

As a bit more context, I have a line chart overlayed on top of a bar chart:

- My bar data is numerical (in the millions, and needs to be rounded and truncated).
- Example: **22345343** needs to be shown as **22M** in the tooltip

---

- My line data is a currency
- Example: **146.36534** needs to shown as **$146.37** in the tooptip

---

Here's my short WIP code thus far. This formats the tooltip to round and include the $ sign.  How can I expand this so that I can separately format my bar data correctly in the tooltip?

---

```
tooltips: {
                mode: 'index',
                intersect: false,
                callbacks: {
                    label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                        return "$" + Number(tooltipItem.yLabel).toFixed(2).replace(/./g, function(c, i, a) {
                                    return i > 0 && c !== "." && (a.length - i) % 3 === 0 ? "," + c : c;
                                });
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Still looking. Just can't figure out how to get multiple data formats specified in the tooltip options since I haven't had luck including in the 'yAxes' subset of options.

Comment: Seems like I might need to use `customTooltips` to be able to define the formats seperately and combine them

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You could achieve that using the following *tooltips callback* function ...

```
callbacks: {
    label: function (t, d) {
        if (t.datasetIndex === 0) {
            return '$' + t.yLabel.toFixed(2)
        } else if (t.datasetIndex === 1) {
            return Math.round(+t.yLabel.toString().replace(/(\d{2})(.*)/, '$1.$2')) + 'M';
        }
    }
}
```

**ᴅᴇᴍᴏ**

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May"],
        datasets: [{
            type: 'line',
            label: "Sales",
            data: [144.36534, 146.42534, 145.23534, 147.19534, 145],
            fill: false,
            borderColor: '#EC932F',
            backgroundColor: '#EC932F',
            tension: 0,
            yAxisID: 'y-axis-2'
        }, {
            type: 'bar',
            label: "Visitor",
            data: [22345343, 23345343, 24345343, 25345343, 230245343],
            backgroundColor: '#71B37C',
            yAxisID: 'y-axis-1'
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: false,
        tooltips: {
            mode: 'index',
            intersect: false,
            callbacks: {
                label: function (t, d) {
                    if (t.datasetIndex === 0) {
                        return '$' + t.yLabel.toFixed(2);
                    } else if (t.datasetIndex === 1) {
                        if (t.yLabel.toString().length === 9) {
                            return Math.round(+t.yLabel.toString().replace(/(\d{3})(.*)/, '$1.$2')) + 'M';
                        } else return Math.round(+t.yLabel.toString().replace(/(\d{2})(.*)/, '$1.$2')) + 'M';
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                id: "y-axis-1",
                position: "left"
            }, {
                id: "y-axis-2",
                position: "right"
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="190"></canvas>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks for the help!

Comment: One small hiccup I'm noticing ... my bar data goes between 20M and 120M. Since the difference between those is an additional digital, the larger one (120M), gets truncated as `12M`, which looks out of place (as a bigger bar) next to say a `20M`

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks again!

Comment: How did you get the colored boxes in the tooltip to match the color of the dataset? And is it possible to perform a calculation between in the tooltip between both dataset?

Answer (score 2):

Try using below code!

```
   let  DoughnutForSavingCount = {
        labels: [
          intl.formatMessage({ id: 'Guarantee' }),
          intl.formatMessage({ id: 'ILAS' }),
          intl.formatMessage({ id: 'No Idea' })
        ],

        datasets: [
          /* Outer doughnut data starts*/

          {
            label: 'Graph1',
            data: [
              _.get(getClientSavingILASPolicyData[0], 'countwithGuaranttee') >
                0 &&
              _.get(getClientSavingILASPolicyData[0], 'totalWithGuarantee') ===
                0
                ? 0.1
                : _.get(getClientSavingILASPolicyData[0], 'totalWithGuarantee'),
              _.get(getClientSavingILASPolicyData[0], 'countwithILAS', 0) > 0 &&
              _.get(getClientSavingILASPolicyData[0], 'totalWithILAS') === 0
                ? 0.1
                : _.get(getClientSavingILASPolicyData[0], 'totalWithILAS'),
              _.get(getClientSavingILASPolicyData[0], 'countNoIdea', 0) > 0 &&
              _.get(getClientSavingILASPolicyData[0], 'totalWithNoIdea') === 0
                ? 0.1
                : _.get(getClientSavingILASPolicyData[0], 'totalWithNoIdea')
            ],
            backgroundColor: ['#8c1aff', '#BF80FF', '#E9e9e9'],
            hoverBackgroundColor: ['#8c1aff', '#BF80FF', '#E9e9e9']
          },
          /* Outer doughnut data ends*/

          /* Inner doughnut data starts*/
          {
            label: 'Graph2',
            data: [
              _.get(getClientSavingILASPolicyData[0], 'countwithGuaranttee'),
              _.get(getClientSavingILASPolicyData[0], 'countwithILAS'),
              _.get(getClientSavingILASPolicyData[0], 'countNoIdea')
            ],
            backgroundColor: ['#8c1aff', '#BF80FF', '#E9e9e9'],
            hoverBackgroundColor: ['#8c1aff', '#BF80FF', '#E9e9e9']
          }
          /* Inner doughnut data ends*/
        ],
        borderWidth: [1]
      };



     let DoughnutForSavingCountConfig = {
          cutoutPercentage: 70,
          legend: {
            display: true,
            position: 'bottom',
            labels: {
              fontColor: '#34A0DC',
              fontSize: 10,
              fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
              boxWidth: 10,
              usePointStyle: true
            }
          },
          responsive: true,
          plugins: {
            datalabels: {
              display: false
            }
          },
          tooltips: {
            enabled: true,
            //*****add for reference********** */
            callbacks: {
              label: function(tooltipItems, data) {
                if (tooltipItems.datasetIndex) {
                  var label = data.labels[tooltipItems.index] || '';
                  var currentValue =
                    data.datasets[tooltipItems.datasetIndex].data[
                      tooltipItems.index
                    ];
                  if (label) {
                    label += ': ';
                  }
                  label += currentValue == '0.1' ? '0' : currentValue;
                  return label;
                } else {
                  var label = data.labels[tooltipItems.index] || '';
                  var currentValue =
                    data.datasets[tooltipItems.datasetIndex].data[
                      tooltipItems.index
                    ];
                  if (label) {
                    label += ': ';
                  }
                  label += intl.formatMessage({ id: 'HKD' }) + ' ';
                  label +=
                    currentValue == '0.1'
                      ? '0'
                      : currentValue
                          .toString()
                          .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
                  return label;
                }
              }
            }
          }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, GRUNT!
But since my datasets could me mixed it's better to use the yAxisID to check for the correct dataset.

```
            tooltips: {
                callbacks: {
                    label: function (tooltipItem, details) {
                        if (details.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].yAxisID == "$") {
                            let dataset = details.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
                            let currentValue = dataset.data[tooltipItem.index];
                            return dataset.label + ": " + currentValue.toFixed(2) + " $";
                        } else {
                            let dataset = details.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
                            let currentValue = dataset.data[tooltipItem.index];
                            return dataset.label + ": " + currentValue +" pieces";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```